# How can I make this online site checker work?

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd, findstr

I'm creating an online site checker (tells you if it's up or down) with CURL on Windows but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried creating a simple script on Windows. First, I check Google with curl and output redirection in statusgoogle.txt file. Then, I ask findstr to find the sentence "Connection established". That means the website is UP. Error code 0 for findstr means it found what it was looking for. So, if it found what it was looking for, I get a message "site is up". If it doesn't find, I get a different error code, so that the message should be "site down".

The problem is:
I get both messages. I already tried using if %errorlevel%, but it didn't work too.

Also, I'd like a code with multiple websites because I'm creating a bat script that actually checks about 9 or 10 website at once.

```
curl -i http://www.google.com/ 1> statusgoogle.txt
findstr /c:"Connection established" statusgoogle.txt
if errorlevel 0 (GOTO :upwarning) else (GOTO :downwarning)
:upwarning
echo site up
:downwarning
echo site down
```

If findstr find the string "Connection established", then I should expect a message with "site up". What it is actually happening is this: it shows both messages "site up" and "site down".

Comment: Also, I'm not willing to use ping because it doesn't work in my case because multiple websites running on the same server with the same IP. Something like: site1.domain.com, site2.domain.com, site3.domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the misunderstandings of the classic `if errorlevel 0` command,
which translates to (see help if)

```
if errorlevel is 0 or greater
```

which is always true for positive errorlevels.

Either

- check `if errorlevel 1` and reverse the logic
  `if errorlevel 1 (GOTO :downwarning) else (GOTO :upwarning)`
- check for the current value of `%errorlevel%`
  `if %errorlevel%==0 (GOTO :upwarning) else (GOTO :downwarning)`
- use conditional execution on success/fail `&&/||`

---

```
curl -i http://www.google.com/ 1> statusgoogle.txt
findstr /c:"Connection established" statusgoogle.txt &&(GOTO :upwarning)||(GOTO :downwarning)

:upwarning
echo site up
goto :eof

:downwarning
echo site down
```

Comment: The issue was also the lack of `goto :eof` between upwarning and downwarning.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after you are jumping to "upwarning" the rest of your code will still be executed. You have to terminate the script after "echo site up":

```
curl -i http://www.google.com/ 1> statusgoogle.txt
findstr /c:"Connection established" statusgoogle.txt
if errorlevel 0 (GOTO :upwarning) else (GOTO :downwarning)
:upwarning
echo site up
goto :EOF
:downwarning
echo site down
```

`:EOF` means "End Of File". "exit /b" will work as well.

Comment: It's not working completely. Now it only shows "site up", no matter what site/webpage. Maybe findstr doesn't have error/return code. Any suggestions, folks?

Comment: With FIND, I have the same results. Return codes don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use PowerShell, it is pretty easy.

```
try {
    Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.hp.com" | Out-Null
    "Web site is up"
} catch {
    "Web site is not up"
}
```